# More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/androidx.localbroadcastmanager_localbroadcastmanager.version' Unity 2019.3

Tags: unity-game-engine

I`m move my Unity project from 2019.2 to 2019.3. After move Android build show error "More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/androidx.localbroadcastmanager_localbroadcastmanager.version'" I`m try set in mainTemplate " exclude 'META-INF/androidx.localbroadcastmanager_localbroadcastmanager.version'", but it not help. How fix this.